# How can I create a custom button link to url

Tags: css, button, joomla

I'm sorry but I'm a newbie and I would like to ask a silly question, is there a way to create a button in css and link to other page?

```css
.ngm-row.clearfix::after {
    content: "more";
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
}
```

I'm trying to do that with this code but I don't know how to link it to url or make it a href.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? are you trying to make a button that navigates too a certain page, with only CSS? because this is not possible CSS is not ment for that.

Comment: You can't create a link with css, if you want to create a link to navigates to a page you have to use html or js

Comment: Thank u Simon M. for your reply. Exactly I wanted to make a button that navigates to a certain page, with only CSS because the page is produced dynamically and I am a little bit confused there.  Again thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS attaches to an HTML element. In your case it looks your  element has a class of `ngm-row`. You will need to wrap your HTML button element in an anchor tag . Then you can set the href of the anchor tag to the page you want to link to.

For example: 
`<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp"><button type="button" class="ngm-row">Click Me!</button></a>`

Comment: No, no, no, you don't put a `button` in an `a`. Never put interactive elements inside one another.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet and your question don't seem to relate, a little more clarification would be helpful.

You will have to create the button/link with HTML and then style it with CSS.

```css
.more-link {
    color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a class="more-link" href="google.com">More</a>
```

If you want the link to look like a button and not a text link, then you will have to use CSS to style it as such.